# What is the relationship between indirect utility function and the expenditure function?

Tags: microeconomics

What is the relationship between indirect utility function and the expenditure function? Explain what accounts for this relationship.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Economics SE. In order to better understand where your problem lies (and to avoid us doing your homework) we ask that you show your own work. Can you please explain what exactly is causing you difficulties?

Comment: This question http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1710/the-relationship-between-the-expenditure-function-and-many-others?rq=1 will probably prove useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

This classic picture from Mas-Colell, Whinston & Green should help you:

[image]

Comment: Images as answers are discouraged (see http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/a/1444/42). Please improve your answer with more explanations (at least the notations in the diagram).